# How to set up synaptics touchpad for smaller fingers?

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

How to set up Synaptics for smaller fingers. With my habitual pressing, it doesn't respond. You'll have to put your fingertip instead of the top.

Comment: size of fingers should not matter, only pressure. If you press harder does it register? that is something that can be configured

Comment: @Esther no. but i actually figured out solution after posting question. i just changed FingerLoe and FingerHigh options.

Comment: that is what I was talking about, and adjusts the pressure required to activate the touchpad

Comment: @Esther oh, sorry for misunderstanding. thanks for answer!

Comment: @HoshimachiTellerstein, when you can, please close out this question as answered so others might be able to easily find the solution in the future. Thanks